# Mojolicious::Lite with Template Toolkit

Tags: perl, web-frameworks, template-toolkit, mojolicious

I'm trying to get Template Toolkit to work as the default renderer in Mojolicious::Lite. What I have:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojolicious::Plugin::TtRenderer;
plugin tt_renderer => { template_options => { INCLUDE_PATH => './tmpl', DEBUG => 1 } };

get '/' => sub {
  my $self = shift;

  $self->render( 'index' );
};

app->renderer->default_handler( 'tt' );
app->start;
```

When I try to hit the test server, I get:

```
[Fri Oct 12 14:02:02 2012] [info] Listening at "http://*:3000". 
Server available at http://127.0.0.1:3000. 
[Fri Oct 12 14:02:08 2012] [debug] Your secret passphrase needs to be changed!!! 
[Fri Oct 12 14:02:08 2012] [debug] GET / (Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0). 
[Fri Oct 12 14:02:08 2012] [debug] Routing to a callback. 
[Fri Oct 12 14:02:08 2012] [debug] Nothing has been rendered, expecting delayed response.
```

This happens regardless of what I pass as parameters to 'render'. I can't seem to figure out how to get any useful debugging information out of this; but I haven't used Mojo before.

I've confirmed by sprinkling in some `warn` statements that my `get` handler is being called.

Comment: Was `TMPL_ROOT` meant to be `INCLUDE_PATH`? `Template::Toolkit` doesn't render anything if it can't find the template.

Comment: Ack, yeah, not sure where `TMPL_ROOT` came from. (It's Friday.) I'm still seeing the same behavior though. :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After looking at the [source](https://metacpan.org/source/PLICEASE/Mojolicious-Plugin-TtRenderer-1.28/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/TtRenderer/Engine.pm) of [Mojolicious::Plugin::TtRenderer::Engine](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojolicious::Plugin::TtRenderer::Engine), I figured it out. The plugin ignores the `INCLUDE_PATH` option passed to Template Toolkit, and instead gets the path from `$app->renderer_paths`. So updating my code to include:

```
app->renderer->default_handler( 'tt' );
app->renderer->paths( [ './tmpl' ] );
```

makes it work.